# Clash when using trivially copy/move-assignable union in constexpr

Tags: c++, c++11, clang, c++14, constexpr

Considering the following code

```
struct S
{
    constexpr S() = default;
    constexpr S(S const &) = default;
    constexpr S(S &) = default;
    constexpr S(S &&) = default;
#if 1
    S & operator = (S const &) = default;
    S & operator = (S &) = default;
    S & operator = (S &&) = default;
#else
    constexpr S & operator = (S const &) = default;
    constexpr S & operator = (S &) = default;
    constexpr S & operator = (S &&) = default;
#endif
    ~S() = default;
};

struct U
{

    union
    {
        S s;
    };

    constexpr U() : s{} { ; }

};

inline constexpr bool test()
{
    U v;
    U w;
    v = w;
    return true;
}

static_assert(test());
```

I found out that there is contradiction.

I want to use `union` (or euqally union-like class) in `constexpr`.

Version `#if 1` gives an error (`error: constexpr function never produces a constant expression`):

```
main.cpp:31:23: error: constexpr function never produces a constant expression [-Winvalid-constexpr]
inline constexpr bool test()
                      ^
main.cpp:35:7: note: non-constexpr function 'operator=' cannot be used in a constant expression
    v = w;
      ^
main.cpp:19:8: note: declared here
struct U
       ^
main.cpp:39:15: error: static_assert expression is not an integral constant expression
static_assert(test());
              ^~~~~~
main.cpp:35:7: note: non-constexpr function 'operator=' cannot be used in a constant expression
    v = w;
      ^
main.cpp:39:15: note: in call to 'test()'
static_assert(test());
              ^
main.cpp:19:8: note: declared here
struct U
       ^
2 errors generated.
```

But version `#if 0` also give an error (`error: defaulted definition of copy assignment operator is not constexpr`):

```
main.cpp:12:5: error: defaulted definition of copy assignment operator is not constexpr
    constexpr S & operator = (S const &) = default;
    ^
main.cpp:13:5: error: defaulted definition of copy assignment operator is not constexpr
    constexpr S & operator = (S &) = default;
    ^
main.cpp:14:5: error: defaulted definition of move assignment operator is not constexpr
    constexpr S & operator = (S &&) = default;
    ^
main.cpp:35:7: error: object of type 'U' cannot be assigned because its copy assignment operator is implicitly deleted
    v = w;
      ^
main.cpp:24:11: note: copy assignment operator of 'U' is implicitly deleted because field 's' has no copy assignment operator
        S s;
          ^
4 errors generated.
```

[LIVE EXAMPLE](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/af83b4cfc330971c)

All above is for version of `clang 3.7.0`, but newer version `clang 3.8.0 (trunk 253951)` nothing says about `constexpr S & operator = (S const &) = default;` (it allows to compile such a code), but consequences are the same.

For trivial copy/move-constructors, but user-provided assignment operators analogous code (construction) compiles fine.

I think the problem (bug) is in user-declared special functions, but it should be legal at all.

Also please look at the last and last but one clauses of [this code](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/00dc7e67747b9f37). Quite well-designed (at my mind) `variant` becomes useless in `constexpr`, due to difference in interpretation by compiler of next definitions:

```
struct S {};
```

and:

```
struct S
{
    constexpr S() = default;
    constexpr S(S const &) = default;
    constexpr S(S &) = default;
    constexpr S(S &&) = default;
    S & operator = (S const &) = default;
    S & operator = (S &) = default;
    S & operator = (S &&) = default;
    ~S() = default;
};
```

But both is equivalent at my mind (the second recognized by compiler as not POD, but who cares?).

Why defaulted assignment operator of empty `struct` is not `constexpr`?

#### UPDATE:

Removing the declaration of destructor makes problem to disappear. So even user-declared (not user-provided) destructor make implicitly defined defaulted assignment operators to be not marked as `constexpr` and to be non-trivial. It definitely bug because no one source telling about this.

Comment: Developing [the library](https://github.com/tomilov/variant/blob/triviality/variant.hpp), I realized that the `union` part of the `clang` and `<type_traits>` part of the `libc++` are extremely poorly tested.

Comment: gcc/clang agrees that the `constexpr` assignation is wrong, but they disagree when it is not marked as `constexpr`: [Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/13075ff7e6ec43be)

Comment: Still persists in clang 13